# what is the default page for spring-mvc application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

IF i have this line in web.xml then i know which is landing page

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Now i want to know that if i don't use that then which is the landing page

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring STS IDE for developing spring mvc application. It's provide home.jsp page which is the default page in spring mvc and you can change easily inside web.xml file of the Spring MVC project Another option you can put your index.jsp page inside webapp folder it's bydefault run first.

Answer (score 0):

[You have the whole documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)!!!

It has got all the answers you may need in your future too.

Usually in an MVC Application, The '/' or 'homepage' is usually not directly called. All requests in an MVC Application should be sent to a dispatcher - servlet who handles all incoming Front End requests and forwards them to respective controllers. You can find a basic Spring MVC Code to create an app [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/)..
[image: MVC Model]